# Run batch file with wine

Tags: wine

So, I've been playing Star Wars: Empire at War recently (with lutris, wine). But, the game is a little boring without mods. So, I downloaded my favorite mod and placed it into the mods folder. The readme tells me to execute a batch file in the games home direction. I pointed lutris at the .bat, and opened the game. It didn't even open. I checked the logs (which are here: https://pastebin.com/f2etC8vT). I opened the batch with gedit, and its contents are: "swfoc MODPATH=Mods\Imperial_Civil_War225"

I am not completely new to linux, nor wine, but i'm still a beginner and it would be great if any of you guys could help. Thanks alot :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your logs that the batch script does not work because it cannot find the executable **swfoc**.

Try setting the full path of the executable in the .bat file, e.g. in your case :

```
C:\GOG Games\Star Wars - Empire At War Gold\swfoc.exe
```

You can also try to run the program directly with wine :

```
wine ./swfoc.exe "MODPATH=Mods\Imperial_Civil_War225"
```

You may need to set `WINEPREFIX` variable to the prefix of your game, e.g. (this is the default) :

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine" wine ./swfoc.exe "MODPATH=Mods\Imperial_Civil_War225"
```

I don't use lutris, so I don't know if there is an easy way to get the path of your prefix in it.

If this works, then you can replace the .bat script with your own shell script to create a launcher :

```
#!/bin/bash
wine ./swfoc.exe "MODPATH=Mods\Imperial_Civil_War225"
```

Paste this in a file (let's call it `launcher`), then save it and run `chmod 755 launcher` to make it executable. You can then run this shortcut directly.